# Time series forecasting for vibration prediction on Industrial machine production?

Tags: machine-learning, python, prediction, forecasting

I'm working on a machine learning project related to an industrial machine.
The goal of the project is to build a model that would be able to predict the vibration of the machine while it's in production on a coil. In particular: the machine starts and the model after some warm up time (collecting data) could be able to predict the vibrational energy in the future (the end of the production).
The dataset is composed by many sensors variables (speed, diameter, accelerometers etc...), some derived variables (thickness, lenght of the coil, etc..) and also it's present the values of the vibrational energy (the one that the model has to predict in the future). So this let me though about a supervised model.
Many working registrations are available (around 4000) of different length.

The first work that I've done (after data understanding) is to clean the data by replacing missing values on every file, discard not consistent registrations (with some physical criteria given by the technicians) and finally i came to a reduced dataset. I've put together the registrations, normalized it and give it to the PCA in order to reduce the dimensionality of the dataset.
Maybe now i should eliminate some redundant registration by looking at the correlation between them, and repeat the PCA. Is there an algorithm to do it?

Now I'm stuck to understand which model could fit well with my problem.
I thought that Time Series Forecasting could be a good choice, but i don't know if the dataset is consistent with the forecasting. Given that I have many registration (15-20 minutes each) in a 2 years span, but not continuous given that the production is often interrupted.
Is the time series forecasting a good choice?